# Is python print function executed by machine code?

Tags: python, bytecode

The CPython gets my input source file written in python and converts it to bytecode. Then, the virtual machine executes this file, like it were a normal CPU environment with a stack for argument passing and an instruction pointer that moves to implement what would be control structures (loop, calls, ifs). Inspecting the bytecode and the SOMEDIR/cpython/Python/ceval.c file, I can see that the virtual machine has a big switch statement that evals on each bytecode instruction.
In this normal operation of the VM, when it reaches functions written in C like print, input, sum, etc, does the code of these functions executes in machine code, previously compiled with the rest of the code of CPython?

Comment: There are definitely parts of CPython (I'm sure as much as they can) that are written in native C and will get compiled with CPython (or in a secondary build step) and then execute "directly in machine code".  I can imagine ``print`` and ``input`` and the like being in that group, though I don't know exactly which pieces are.  But yes, architecturally, you've described things accurately.

Comment: Ok. I'll keep that in mind. If I need heavy computations I'll write the c code and compile and find out how to call and pass arguments from python.